# Does Hyperledger Fabric support user logs?

Tags: logging, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I would like to see the historical transactions that a user does, for example if a user modify an asset or create an asset.

I have tried with `getHistoryforkey` to see the historical modification in an asset but it does not have the user who did the modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The history will have the transaction ID on it, and from there you can look up the details of the transaction which will have the signature of who did the modification.

Comment: I know the transaction structure but in the signature zone it only has the client application not the user signature, Am I wrong?....

"Signature: This section, illustrated by S4, contains a cryptographic signature, created by the client application. This field is used to check that the transaction details have not been tampered with, as it requires the application’s private key to generate it."

Comment: The client application has to have credentials to be a user. It must have some information that can be used to create a transaction for execution/endorsement and then submission to the orderer.If you're talking about a totally separate client that can only query, the creds for access to the channel maybe don't have enough? I'm not entirely sure